# angular-translate : sanitize strategies

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-translate

in my ionic app, there's a tag where I need to use

```
$translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('sanitize');
```

because there is html in the translation field (translation-fr.js):

```
"recommendedboard": "Prefer a <span class=\"animateFUN\">SMALL-WAVE</span> board</span>"
```

But there are others spots where I need to use

```
$translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('escape');
```

because in the French translation, there accents on some letters, like :

```
 "31": "Modèle"
```

The only solution I found for now is to use the `null` strategy. Is there a way to use both strategies, or to specify the strategy for each translation ?

I have this in index.html:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

and I checked the translation-fr.js file:

```
$ file -bi www/js/dicts/translation-fr.json 
text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I used

```
$translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('sanitizeParameters');
```

and now it seems to work for both case.